# Cortar Array en X caracteres e imprimirlo por pantalla en php

Tags: php, array, string

tengo un campo en una base de datos con un campo llamado "Texto" el cual contiene un string muy largo (unos 200 caracteres), necesito cortar dicha cadena de texto en un máximo de 80 palabras, para ello estoy haciendo el siguiente código:

```
<?php


    $usuario = "XXXX";
    $password = "XXXX";
    $servidor = "localhost:3306";
    $basededatos = "XXXX";
    
    // creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
    $conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $password) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
    
    // Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
    $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );

    // establecer y realizar consulta. guardamos en variable.
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Entradas";
    $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

    // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
    while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
    {
        $Tamano = strlen($columna['texto']) ;
        $TextoBruto = $columna['texto'];
        $array_cadena = str_word_count($TextoBruto, 1);
        $Tamano_array = count($array_cadena);
            
            
            
            for ($contador =0 ; $contador < $Tamano_array; $contador++)
            {

                $Palabras = 80;

                echo "<div>";
                echo "<p>";
                for ($i=0; $i<$Palabras;$i++)
                {
                    $firstElement = $array_cadena[$i];
                    echo $firstElement . " ";
                }
                echo "</p>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
    }

    // cerrar conexión de base de datos
    mysqli_close( $conexion );
?>
```

el problema es que me crea 200 divs iguales (La longitud de la cadena) en lugar de crearme varios divs con el texto repartido en dichos divs. Ejemplo:

Este seria un ejemplo de cadena larga

Si la divido en 3 palabras saldría la siguiente cadena

"Este Seria Un" "Ejemplo de cadena" "Larga".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varias cosas a corregir, a saber:

1. Defines **variables de un solo uso que apuntan a otras variables anteriores**, cosa que yo reduzco en mi solución final usando solo las variables anteriores.
2. Usas la función **str_word_count()** que puede ser peligrosa porque *desaparecen algunos caracteres especiales como las comas o puntos*, por lo tanto lo he cambiado por un explode() usando como separador de palabras el espacio.
3. Dos **echo** seguidos no tienen sentido (al menos para mi) y los he unificado siempre que he podido.
4. He definido una nueva variable dentro del primer bucle que se inicializa en cada ciclo denominada **$salida** que va a contener despues la cantidad de palabras que establezcas en la variable **$Palabras** pues la uso dentro del segundo ciclo para almacenar su resultado en lugar de hacer un `echo`. El motivo es para después usar la función [rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rtrim.php) que nos va a eliminar el espacio sobrante final de cada grupo de palabras antes de cerrar el *div*.
5. Dentro del segundo bucle uso la función [array_shift()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-shift) que nos va a devolver el primer valor del array **$array_cadena**, eliminándolo del mismo e impidiendo que se pueda volver a repetir.
6. También en el segundo bucle incremento (**++**) la variable **$contador** para ir restando las palabras que vamos quitando del número de ciclos pendientes de realizar en el primer bucle.
7. Fuera del bucle decremento (**--**) la variable **$contador** para contrarestar el último incremento del segundo bucle. De otro modo se puede perder la última palabra.
8. Fuera del segundo bucle, pero aún en el primero, utilizo la función **rtrim()** sobre la variable **$salida** que nos va a *eliminar el último espacio* producido en la última iteración del segundo bucle y que de no hacerlo nos dejaría un espacio antes del cierre del párrafo.

Todo esto se traduce en este código:

```php
$array_cadena = explode(" ", $columna['texto']);
$Tamano_array = count($array_cadena);
for ($contador =0 ; $contador < $Tamano_array; $contador++) {
    $Palabras = 80;
    echo "<div><p>";
    $salida = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<$Palabras;$i++) {
        $salida .= array_shift($array_cadena)." ";
        $contador++;
    }
    $contador--;
    echo rtrim($salida," ")."</p></div>";
}
```

Comment: me parece que el contador esta de mas pero en todo lo demas parece bien,esa sintaxis se ve muy desarrollador VBS xd jaja

Comment: @RockMares No se ni lo que es VBS, la verdad... Visual Basic?... Tampoco entiendo eso de quitar el contador... de donde lo quitarias tu? Si tienes una mejor aportación que dar quiźas podrias ponerla como respuesta y así la comunidad lo agradecerá. Este código está comprobado en mi PC y aparentemente funciona bien.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, llevo horas dandole vueltas al tema y no lo lograba, me has solucionado un gran problema, estoy aprendiendo y gente como tu que lo explica tan claro son un gran aporte.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado y que te hayas leido todo mi rollo (no todos lo hacen) :-)  Saludos!